# find first index of array in string javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is a string variable that has a path like **/app/something/xx/4/profile**
besides there is an array of string like **

```
const arr=[
     {name:'xx',etc...}, 
     {name:'yy',etc...},
     {name:'zz',etc...}
    ]
```

I want to find the first index of array that the string variable has the name in simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which :

> returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns -1, indicating that no element passed the test.

```js
const str = "/app/something/xx/4/profile";

const arr = [{ name: "xx" }, { name: "yy" }, { name: "zz" }];

const index = arr.findIndex(e => str.includes(e.name));

console.log({ index });
```